# USB flash drive disconnecting and reconnecting continually

Tags: windows-xp, usb, usb-flash-drive

**Short question**
One of my flash drives is continually disconnecting and reconnecting on Windows XP. I plugged it in and for few seconds I can see a drive letter in "My Computer". After few seconds it disappears and then reappears.

How can I fix it?

**Details**
Flash drive works because it works on Linux on the same computer and works properly on another computer (with Windows XP too). Another flash drive works without any problem on that computer and Windows XP.

I tried removing drivers but it didn't work. After a reinstall the problem shows up again. In the USB Root Hub Properties I unchecked "Allow the computer to turn off this device to save power". It also didn't work.

Comment: Have you tried using a different USB port?

Comment: Yes but nothing has changed. It works on same usb port on another OS, and another flash drive works in same usb port on windows.

Comment: Sounds like a corrupted driver (e.g. tries to install, fails, uninstalls, then "refinds" the hardware, loop).  Try running the *sfc* tool to scan the Windows system files to check for any corruptions, and report back.

Comment: Cant be sure that this will work but try this: run->devmgmt.msc->USB Root Hub properties -> Power management -> dont allow OS to turn of usb port. Can also try to disable USB legacy support in the BIOS

Comment: @Breakthrought Scan with sfc didn't find anything. (After scan it didn't show anything so I think that it didn't find...)

Comment: Curious is that the problematic flash drive works on that computer two days ago but yesterday didn't work again.

Comment: I had a similar issue, which I posted here, but got deleted as it was not an answer, which I later found. [I reposted it as a new question with the answer here](http://superuser.com/questions/922287/usb-flash-drive-disconnecting-and-reconnecting-continuously).

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this problem a few times in recent years with various USB devices and NICs (Network Interface Cards).  The solution was to perform a deep power cycle, which is done as follows:

1. Shut down your computer (gracefully, using the Operating System's proper "shut down" procedure)
2. After the computer is powered off, disconnect the AC power (if using a laptop, remove the battery too) and the video display and any other devices that have their own power supplies/sources
3. Try to turn the computer on at least three times by pressing the power button
4. Re-connect all devices and the AC power (if using a laptop, re-install the battery first)
5. Turn the computer on and try to use your USB device again

Step number 3 is what qualifies this as a "deep power cycle" and it is essential with no power sources connected because it has the effect of draining capacitors and other electronic components in your computer that might be retaining an inappropriate [yet subtle] charge.

Comment: I tried this but I didn't not success. I think that it it is not hardware error because flash disk works on the same computer but not same operation system.

Comment: You're right -- that definitely points to software.