# USB flash drive disconnecting and reconnecting continuously

Tags: windows-7, usb-flash-drive, power

I have almost the exact same issue as described [here](https://superuser.com/questions/207307/usb-flash-drive-disconnecting-and-reconnecting-continually) with my flash drive, but on Windows 7. 
My flash drive disconnects and reconnects continuously every few seconds, on the USB 2.0 ports, **BUT** on my computers, it doesn't actually connect, with the disconnection sound emitted every ~2 seconds. Instead I get a message saying USB device not recognised, and of course, this message reappears every few seconds every time the device reconnects. When I connect to a USB 3.0 port, nothing happens at all. No connection.

I have a 32 GB flash drive ([Kingston DataTraveler 100](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Kingston-Technology-32GB-DataTraveler-Generation/dp/B00C5K8E1A)), which was working fine last night, but this morning, all of a sudden, stopped working. I tried on 3 different computers, all with the same issue reoccurring.

Nothing appears on My Computer and so I went to the went to the Computer Management app (right-click on my computer and choose manage) and nothing ever appears on the device manager or the disk management.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Please cut your Solution out of your "Question" and post it as an "Answer".

Comment: possible duplicate of [USB flash drive disconnecting and reconnecting continually](http://superuser.com/questions/207307/usb-flash-drive-disconnecting-and-reconnecting-continually)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I somehow fixed my flash drive by accident. I figured the problem was power related and so I removed the casing and looked inside. There was nothing wrong. Nothing was bent or burnt. Everything looked pristine. I cleaned it anyway, with a soft toothbrush, both the electronics and the inside of the USB connection port. I connected the flash drive back to the computer, with the problem still persisting, and took a multimeter to see if it was indeed receiving 5 volts. I found the USB 3.0 pin-out on Google images:

[image: 1]

I first measured across pins 1, VBUS, and 4, GND, and got fluctuating readings below 0.9 V. I then tried pins 1 and 7, which was the GND for the USB 3.0 part of the device, with the same reading.

As I was removing the multimeter tip, I accidentally touched pins 7 and 8 (data -), and a small spark appeared. Unbelievably it then connected to the computer and I immediately backed up the files I needed, with no problems. It stayed connected with no issues, during the back up, which took 10 mins.

After backing up my stuff, I disconnected and reconnected it, but the issue reoccurred. I again took my multimeter tip and touched pins 7 and 8 together, this time on purpose. No spark this time, but the flash drive connected to the computer and now it works fine no matter how many times I disconnect and reconnect it (not that I'll ever use it again). I also connected it to the USB 3.0 port again and it worked just fine.

Freak accidental solution for a freak problem.

Hope it can help anyone out there.